# My login system will not work - regardless of any user passwords entered

Tags: python, authentication

My sign up and login authentication system is not working as it is supposed to. My signup issue was fixed, but my login has a problem. Either the code will let me go through and access the account, or it will not, depending on the code. But anytime I try to fix it, the output is one of the two options. ALWAYS, regardless of the password I enter.

The usernames and passwords are stored in a txt file, like this:

```
John Appleseed:hisSuperSecretPassword
JohnDoe:1234
```

The login code:

```
found = False
username = input("Enter your username:\n")
file = open("account.txt", "r+")
    
for line in file:
    if line.split(':')[0] == username:
        found = True
if found == True:
    password = input("Enter your password:\n")

    for counter, line in enumerate(file):
            
        if line.strip() == username + ":" + password:
            print("You have signed in.")
        else:
            print("Password incorrect. Program closing.")
            sys.exit()
else:
    print("Username not valid.")
    sys.exit()
```

Can anyone help? Running Python 3.9.2.

Comment: You haven't indicated that you've debugged this yet, or if you did, how. Did you try printing `line.split(':')[0]`, `line.strip()`, as well as `username + ":" + password`, to see what they actually contain? That would be my first step in debugging this.

Comment: You have read one or more lines from the file, while looking for a match for the username.  The `enumerate()` then reads through the *rest* of the file looking for a full match including the password, but that doesn't include the actual user's entry which you've already read.

Comment: Put `file.seek(0)` before the 2nd loop. Or better still, create a lookup table from the file: `users = dict(line.strip().split(':') for line in file if line.strip())`. Then you can simply check that `users.get(username) == password`.

Comment: Yes, I have debugged it, many times before I put it on stack overflow. 2nd comment: I removed it then tried again, but it would do the same thing: accept or refuse me, regardless of the password. 3rd comment: i will try that, but i don't understand completely

Comment: Your code has two main faults: one that you use up the file in the first loop, and the second is that your program exits when it finds a single wrong entry. Perhaps simplest is just to remove the `for counter, line in enumerate(file)`, so you're re-using the line that matches the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I've adjusted to work....

```
import sys

found = False
username = input("Enter your username:\n")
file = open("account.txt", "r+")
    
for line in file:
    if line.split(':')[0] == username:
        account_details = line.split(':')
        found = True

if found == True:
    password = input("Enter your password:\n")
    if account_details[1].strip() == password:
        print("You have signed in.")
    else:
        print("Password incorrect. Program closing.")
        sys.exit()
else:
    print("Username not valid.")
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exiting the program as soon as you find a non-matching password, instead of comparing the password to the correct user. You also don't need to re-read the entire password file: you already found the expected password when you verified that the user name existed.

As an aside, there's no sense confirming for an attacker that they have correctly guessed a user name. Just get the user name and password first, then look for them in the password file.

```
username = input("Enter your username:\n")
password = input("Enter your password:\n")

with open("account.txt") as fh:
    if any(f'{username}:{password}' == line.strip() for line in fh):
        print("You have signed in.")
    else:
        print("Invalid username or password, exiting")
        sys.exit()
```